# How can I reference this data in this JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am using d3.js's "d3.json(); function to reach out and fetch some data from a REST API.

The data comes back as this:

```
{
"offset" : 0,
"rows": [
{ "_id":
    { "$oid" : "1234567" }, 
      "mockupData" : [ { 
          "Analysis" : "Test", 
          "Description" : "The Test indicates...", 
          "Data" : [
             { "Category" : "A", 
               "Statistic" : 0.15, 
               "Value" : 0.95 }, 
             { "Category" : "B", 
               "Statistic" : 0.65, 
               "Value" : 0.85 }, 
             ] } ] }
           ],
  "total_rows" : 1 ,
  "query" : {} ,
  "millis" : 0
}
```

I am having an extremely difficult time drilling down in to the json to get what I want.

I'm attempting to set it up like this:

```
function generateChart(){
    var chart;
    var Category = [{key:"Stuff", values:[]}];
    d3.json('http://url_that_returns_json/', function(error,data{
       for(var key in data._SOMETHING_){
          switch(key){
             case "A":
                 Category[0] ["values"].push({"label":"Statistic","value""data.Category[key]});
... // same for B
})

// more graph logic
```

I appear to be missing some entire fragment of knowledge on this. Guidance? Help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle I have implemented : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/486mwb86/1/

First off, I set the data as a variable so I can use it later. So :

```
var data = {
  "offset": 0,
  "rows": [{
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "1234567"
    }, ... //and so on
```

This is exactly the same as you using :

```
d3.json('http://url_that_returns_json/', function(error,data{
```

Both data variables are the same.

Then I got to the point you wanted to check, i.e the categories in the data attribute, like so :

```
var thisDataSet = data.rows[0].mockupData[0].Data;
```

As this is an array and not an object, I used a for loop to loop through :

```
for (var i = 0; i < thisDataSet.length; i++) {
```

And, in my opinion, you didn't need a switch statement as it looks like you just wanted to populate `Category.values` with the different categories. So I just pushed the current value of the category in the dataset to this `Category.values` :

```
 Category[0]["values"].push({
      "label": "Statistic",
      "value": thisDataSet[i].Category //push category here
    });
```

And that's it. Check the console log for output. Should work fine. Full function :

```
function generateChart() {
  var chart;
  var Category = [{
    key: "Stuff",
    values: []
  }]; 
  console.log(data.rows[0].mockupData[0].Data)
  var thisDataSet = data.rows[0].mockupData[0].Data;
  for (var i = 0; i < thisDataSet.length; i++) {
    //for (var key in data.rows[0].mockupData[0].Data) {
    console.log(thisDataSet[i]) 
    Category[0]["values"].push({
      "label": "Statistic",
      "value": thisDataSet[i].Category
    });  
  }
  console.log(Category) 
}
```

Comment: I shall explain what I did, but is that what you wanted ? Check the console log

Comment: That certainly gets me down the road and I sincerely appreciate the help. I follow what you did, but I'm all about a good walkthrough. I'll make some changes and see how much further I can get, then post results.

Comment: @Kickasstimus check updated answer, explanation added

Comment: Thanks again. Ultimately, I need to create a bar chart from the values in the Category; Statistic and Value. I think I see how to proceed.

Comment: ok, simple, just use Categoy.values and pass it to a function that creates d3 bar chart

Comment: @Kickasstimus check this fiddle I threw together : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/486mwb86/3/ Creates a bar chart with your data. Tweaked a little as it needs integers not strings to work out the height whereas in your case you only have strings for both value and label :) That help ?

Comment: you are awesome! Thanks!